# Enabling OverlayFS on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, overlayfs

I understand that to enable overlay file system we nedd to make changes in the overlayroot.conf file and reboot the system. But is it possible without rebooting my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /etc/overlayroot.conf file only exists if you install the package overlayroot, an encrypted overlay for use in cloud environments.
Here's an article about [Overlayroot](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2012/08/introducing-overlayroot-overlayfs.html) by it's creator Dustin Kirkland.

The overlayroot.conf file is unnecessary if you just want to mount an overlay filesystem.
Overlayfs is available and ready to use as soon as your Trusty Tahr installation is complete.

I'd been struggling to get an overlay filesystem to work for / right from boot without mounting it manually, but was directed to the very useful askubuntu wiki [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash#Overlayfs). Very useful to rebuild the initramfs, and get the overlayfs in place as soon as your system starts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i just want to test overlayFS and so want to mount it on a loopback device.Have any Suggestions?

Comment: thanks for answering again.what is that overlayname you mentioned overthere in the above comment

Comment: I removed that overlayname thing and it worked fine..i could mount overlayfs...but couldnt get what overlayname is

Comment: @Arronical I am having a bit of trouble getting overlayfs working at boot using that script.  I setup the script as it describes but it just hangs at boot.  I can use the disable-root-ro=true flag and it boots normally, so I know the script is running.  Any assistance would be great.  Did you have to setup partitions or fstab in a specific way?